# Parallelizing the fuzzy string comparison algorithm

Tags: python, parallel-processing, numba, fuzzy-search

I can’t parallelize the fuzzy string comparison algorithm using the Winnowing method using the Numba library. How can this be implemented? I encounter many errors when trying to fix the problem. Where **`data`** is an array of strings, **`dataHash`** is an array of hashes of strings.

```
@njit
def winnowing( data,                   # an array of strings
               dataHash,               # an array of hashes of strings
               threshold = 0.85        # a threshold for jaccard()
               ):
    for          i in range( len( dataHash ) ):
        for      j in range( len( dataHash ) ):
            if ( i == j or dataHash[j] == None ):
                 continue
            if ( threshold <= jaccard( str( dataHash[i] ),
                                       str( dataHash[j] )
                                       )
                 ):
                 dataHash[j] = None
                 data[    j] = None

    return( data )
```

Errors are usually of the form :

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline
                                  (step: nopython frontend)
                                   non-precise type array(pyobject, 2d, C)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Community of Merit. You might have already read the advice how to best ask questions, so kindly revise your post, so as to include all components so as to become an MCVE - a **M**inimum (in scale), **C**omplete (can re-run with exemplified data) **V**erifiable (leaving no magic inside) **E**xample of the Problem-under-Review. Following this Community principle will allow you to receive highest value from the Community Members, who sponsor their time & knowhow to help you solve a Problem-under-Review. Ignoring the MCVE-rules shows not to be a wise strategy on this site.